# How to resolve this equation $(2x-1)^{-3} = 27$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

I try to resolve this equation because the ask I think is nót correct. can explain the steps for resolve this?
[image: Resolução do exercício]

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please type your question rather than posting an image since images cannot be searched.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: $a^b = c \implies a = c^{1/b}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should read:

$$(2x-1)^{-3} = 27 \implies \frac{1}{(2x-1)^{\color{red}{3}}} = 27 \implies (2x-1)^{\color{red}{3}} = \frac{1}{27} \implies 2x-1 = \frac{1}{3}.$$